# How capture KeyDown for another application?

Tags: c#, capture, keydown

How can I capture KeyDown from another application?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense to me - could you explain what you want to do?

Comment: This question makes perfect sense - I'm not sure why you guys are down-voting it.

Comment: it is a perfect question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to globally hook into the keyboard: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx

To know that a keystroke has come from a particular application, you will need to know what the active window is (i.e. the window that is currently receiving the keystrokes): http://www.csharphelp.com/2006/08/get-current-window-handle-and-caption-with-windows-api-in-c/